# How to add and retrieve "fill in the blanks" spaces and answers in database using PHP & jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to give input as a paragraph and I will choose a number of blanks (for the user to fill with an answer) needed for the paragraph. And also I will add a answer list for each blank space. My question is how can I add that paragraph with inserted blanks in the database and later show the paragraph on the UI. I'll also need to be able to pull the list of possible answers for each blank.

[image]

Please can anyone suggest a way to add the blank spaces in the paragraph before saving to the database and how can I get where all the blanks are added in the paragraph. I need to show these blanks in UI, and I also need the correct answers for that particular blank. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could split the paragraph into an array and insert the space at the end of each index. That way you could use the current index to determine which list of "answers" to load. Please add in your db schema.

Comment: paragraph - varchar(1000),numberofchoice-varchar(100),answers-varchar(1000)

Comment: Could you send me any sample code for this scenario

Comment: For the paragraph, insert an `*` where you want each blank, then use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to build the array of strings that precede each blank.

Comment: Even in paragraph there may be some * delimiter right. And how can you differentiate first choice second choice and all

Comment: you can use any delimiter that you feel wont be in the paragraph normally. The strings will get put into an array and you can access them by the index. If you packaged them into an array called $strings then $strings[0] would be the paragraph up until the first space, and you could pull the first group of answers for that space.

Comment: I can't ask the client to add delimiter inside paragraph typing.Instead as I shown in picture I want to drag and drag choice 1 and the position where he/she dropped is taken as first blank similarly for all blanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131113/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-mtrueblood).